# username for sql server connection through php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to php. I don't understand why database can still be connected when I use any username. for example, when I tried:

```
mysql_connect('localhost','zcvbfd','');
```

there is no any error message shown up. the return value is: `Resource id #3`

Comment: **Obligatory suggestion**, [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2):

Many default MySQL installations allow for userless, passwordless connections to MySQL from localhost.

Best practice is to disable this. You can run: `sudo mysql_secure_installation`

OR Login as root or another privileged mysql user and run:

```
SELECT host FROM mysql.user WHERE user = '';
```

And then for each hostname it gives you run:

```
DROP USER ''@'hostname-here';
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! May I know how to disable this? Thanks!

Comment: if unix, you also could just run `sudo mysql_secure_installation` and follow the steps, +1

Comment: Works! Thanks Sammitch!